# How to reset a reducer which uses the same key but a different action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

So this is my current reducer:

```
import { Reducer } from 'redux';
import {
  EventState,
  LOAD_EVENTS,
  LOAD_EVENT_BY_ID,
  FETCH_MORE_EVENTS
} from '../types/eventTypes';

export const initialState = {
  eventsList: [],
  event: undefined,
  isLastPage: false
};

const eventReducers: Reducer<EventState, any> = (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_EVENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        eventsList: action.eventsList
      };
    case FETCH_MORE_EVENTS:
      return {
        state,
        eventsList: state.eventsList.concat(action.eventsList),
        isLastPage: action.eventsList.length === 0
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default eventReducers;
```

As you see both cases `LOAD_EVENTS` and `FETCH_MORE_EVENTS` share the key `eventsList`, on fetch more events I am calling state like this `state` instead of `...state` because it seems to re init the state of the whole reducer. But, is that the proper way? I think that if this reducer grows up, that will be a bug.

So what can I do to clean that reducer properly to make? Like all I need is that `LOAD_EVENTS` fires then `eventsList` should get clear and fill out again by what `LOAD_EVENTS` brings. And basically I only need to reset the state of `eventsList` but rest should remain the same.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _"because it seems to re init the state"_? What does `state` and `action` look like when `LOAD_EVENTS` is called? How about `FETCH_MORE_EVENTS`? Can you post the objects in both instances so we can see what they look like?

Answer (score 1):

when you calling state like `state` instead of `...state`, you aren't re-init the state, but storing the previous state inside the new state, like this example below:

```
state = {
  eventsList: [...someEvents],
  event: undefined,
  isLastPage: false,
  state: {
    eventsList: [...someEvents],
    event: undefined,
    isLastPage: false,
    state: {
      eventsList: [...someEvents],
      event: undefined,
      isLastPage: false
    }
  }
};
```

This is not a good pattern/practice, only if is super necessary.

So the correct, it's reset the previous state with initialState when fetch more events.

```
export const initialState = {
  eventsList: [],
  event: undefined,
  isLastPage: false
};

const eventReducers: Reducer<EventState, any> = (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_EVENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        eventsList: action.eventsList
      };
    case FETCH_MORE_EVENTS:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        eventsList: state.eventsList.concat(action.eventsList),
        isLastPage: action.eventsList.length === 0
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But how you say, it's only need to reset the state of `eventsList` but rest should remain the same, you can keep the same to this reducer:

```
case LOAD_EVENTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    eventsList: action.eventsList
};
```

Because when you set `eventsList` like the example above, you are reset the `eventsList` and fill out again with new data. But don't forget the problem about the first example that I say.